# Trello API - Create a new Card - name

Tags: javascript, trello, node-fetch

I'm trying to create a new card in JavaScript with the Trello API. I have this:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=${key}&token=${token}&idList=${listId}&desc=test&name=${name}`, {
method: 'POST'
})
```

It works. But if the name ist `test#1` it only save `test`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try surrounding `test#1` with double-quotes?  "test#1"

Comment: @CodingSomething No, `"test#1"` will save `"test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to encode first.
Ex-
"John#1" will be encoded to "John%231"

You can check this site -> https://www.urlencoder.org/